# How to change the dataApiPort option during Azure Static Web Application deployment using SWA CLI?

Tags: azure, database-connection, svelte, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to deploy a [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) web application to an Azure Static Web Application (SWA) using the `swa` CLI tool. I have created a serverless "Cosmos DB NoSQL" database and a "Static Web App" resource on Azure. The simple web application deployment was successful and I managed to link the Cosmos DB with the Static Web App using the [SWA CLI](https://azure.github.io/static-web-apps-cli/) tool on my Linux (Debian 12) machine.

## Deployment steps

However, I could **not** deploy the application on my **Windows** (workplace) **machine**. I had been following the [Database connection Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/database-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=bash) tutorials. First, I exported the connection string from the database:

```bash
export DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING='<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>'
```

Next, I installed the `swa` CLI tool globally:

```bash
npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
```

I am using the `/build` folder for deployment hence I built the app with the `npm run build` command. Here is the content of the `svelte.config.js` config file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        }),
        // This option is necessary for the GitHub page deployment
        paths: {
            base: process.argv.includes('dev') ? '' : process.env.BASE_PATH
        }
    }
};
```

But, when I start the SWA emulator with the following command:

```bash
swa start ./build --data-api-location swa-db-connections
```

On Windows (I did **not** get any error on Linux), I got the following error message:

```
[dataApi] Information: Microsoft.DataApiBuilder 0.9.7+e560142426d1c080b9fd7b7fabff51a276f6bf61
[dataApi] Information: User provided config file: staticwebapp.database.config.json
[dataApi] Loading config file from staticwebapp.database.config.json.
[dataApi] Information: Loaded config file: staticwebapp.database.config.json       
[dataApi] Information: Setting default minimum LogLevel: Error for Production mode.
[dataApi] Starting the runtime engine...
[dataApi] Redirecting to https is disabled.
[dataApi] Loading config file from staticwebapp.database.config.json.
[dataApi] info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
[dataApi]       User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\z0190983\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[swa] 
[swa] Using workflow file:
[swa]   C:\Users\z0190983\ws\personal\pomodoro-svelte\.github\workflows\azure-static-web-apps.yml
[dataApi] Unable to launch the runtime due to: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
[dataApi]  ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
[dataApi]  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
[dataApi]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
[dataApi]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
[dataApi]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
```

I checked the with `netstat -na | findstr :5000`, and indeed it is listening. If I execute the `swa --print-config` command, I will see that the `dataApiPort` is the 5000 port:

```
Options:
 - port: 4280
 - host: localhost
 - apiPort: 7071
 - dataApiPort: 5000
 - appLocation: .
 - apiLocation: <undefined>
 - dataApiLocation: swa-db-connections
 - outputLocation: build
...
```

Now, the question is how can I change the `dataApiPort` options to another port? I tried using the `swa start --port 5000` with no vain. I would really appreciate any help and guidance!

> Note: You can also clone the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SzilvasiPeter/pomodoro-svelte) to quickly reproduce the problem.

## Configuration files (Optional)

The configuration files are the exact copy from the tutorial but here are they, just in case. Under the `swa-db-connections` folder, this is the content of the `staticwebapp.database.config.json` file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/download/v0.9.7/dab.draft.schema.json",
    "data-source": {
        "database-type": "cosmosdb_nosql",
        "connection-string": "@env('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING')",
        "options": {
            "database": "MyTestPersonDatabase",
            "schema": "staticwebapp.database.schema.gql"
        }
    },
    "runtime": {
        "graphql": {
            "enabled": true,
            "path": "/graphql",
            "allow-introspection": true
        },
        "host": {
            "cors": {
                "origins": ["http://localhost:4280"],
                "allow-credentials": false
            },
            "authentication": {
                "provider": "StaticWebApps"
            },
            "mode": "production"
        }
    },
    "entities": {
        "Person": {
            "source": "MyTestPersonContainer",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "actions": ["*"],
                    "role": "anonymous"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The content of the `staticwebapp.database.schema.gql` file:

```
type Person @model {
    id: ID
    Name: String
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by killing the process that occupied the 5000 port. I checked the process ID with this command:

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8080

  TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6764
  TCP    [::1]:5000             [::]:0                 LISTENING       6764
```

I looked at the `6764` pid with `tasklist /fi "pid eq 6764"` command and it was the **OneApp.IGCC.WinService.exe** process. It is a service from Intel and I do not know what it is doing but according to the [Stop the service OneApp.IGCC.WinService](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/stop-the-service-oneappigccwinservice/4c9a4fdf-8cc3-4021-a612-b902a64d1c33) forum post:

> it is not necessary to have that service running

Therefore I killed the process:

```
taskkill /pid 6764 /F
```

And the deployment was successful.

It is not very elegant... because every time I need to kill this process. Alternatively, there is the [OneApp.IGCC.WinService using port 5000](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/OneApp-IGCC-WinService-using-port-5000/m-p/1543661#M124733) post from the Intel community to change the port permanently:

> Here's what I did:
>
> 1. Open the Registry Editor (as always, be careful in there).
> 2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\igccservice.
> 3. Double-click the ImagePath key.
> 4. Append after the quotes: --urls http://127.0.0.1:50000 Click OK. Restart the service.
> 5. Click OK.
> 6. Restart the service.